# error Non-static method sessions::set_sessions

Tags: php

I get these error lines:

```
[29-Jan-2016 00:27:59 Africa/Cairo] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method sessions::set_sessions() should not be called statically in /home/trizipo/public_html/admin/controller/login.php on line 120
[29-Jan-2016 00:27:59 Africa/Cairo] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method sessions::set_sessions() should not be called statically in /home/trizipo/public_html/admin/controller/login.php on line 122
[29-Jan-2016 00:27:59 Africa/Cairo] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method sessions::set_sessions() should not be called statically in /home/trizipo/public_html/admin/controller/login.php on line 124
[29-Jan-2016 00:27:59 Africa/Cairo] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method sessions::set_sessions() should not be called statically in /home/trizipo/public_html/admin/controller/login.php on line 126
[29-Jan-2016 00:27:59 Africa/Cairo] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method sessions::set_sessions() should not be called statically in /home/trizipo/public_html/admin/controller/login.php on line 128
[29-Jan-2016 00:27:59 Africa/Cairo] PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method sessions::set_sessions() should not be called statically in /home/trizipo/public_html/admin/controller/login.php on line 130
```

concerning this code:
[code pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W51kd.jpg)
Is there a solution?

Comment: As the message says, the `set_sessions()` method is a non static one, while writing `sessions::set_sessions()` you're calling it as static. You can only use a instance of the `sessions` class, say `mySessions` and call `mySessions->set_sessions()`. Anyway we can't help you more without viewing the class code.

Answer (score 0):

The method `set_sessions` within your `sessions` class does not contain the [static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). If you intended to call it statically it should look like this:

```
class sessions
{
    ....

    public static function set_sessions($key, $value)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```